# Saving List of Objects Throws Hibernate Exception

Tags: java, hibernate

When I am saving a `List` of objects by calling `saveListOfPageChooserElement`, it throws the below exception

Whereas, when I am saving a single instance by calling `saveOrUpdate`, then it works fine.

But to improve performance I want to save a List batch rather than single object at a time.

Can anyone suggest what's the problem with saving a whole list at once?

```
 List<Abc> listabc = widgetCopyDAO
                    .fetchabcByPageId(id);


    for (Abc abc: listabc ) {
                abc.setLastUpdatedBy(null);
                abc.setLastUpdatedOn(null);
                abc.setCreatedBy(widgetCopyDTO.getUserName());
                abc.setCreatedOn(new Date());
                abc.setPageChooser(new PageChooser(chooser.getId()));



                abc.setId(0l);
                issuePageWidgetDAO.saveOrUpdate(abc);
            }
//  widgetCopyDAO.saveListOfPageChooserElement(listabc);


public void saveOrUpdate(Abc abc) {
        if (abc.getId() == 0) {
            Long id = (Long) this.getHibernateTemplate().save(
                    abc);
            abc.setId(id);
        } else {
            this.getHibernateTemplate().update(abc);
        }
    }


public void saveListOfPageChooserElement(
            List<Abc> listabc) {
        this.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdateAll(listabc);

    }
```

The exception is

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: identifier of an instance of com.mct.model.Abc was altered from 138 to 0; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.mct.model.Abc was altered from 138 to 0
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:676)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1048)
    at com.mct.dao.WidgetCopyDAO.fetchPageChooserWithImagesByChooser(WidgetCopyDAO.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy58.fetchPageChooserWithImagesByChooser(Unknown Source)
    at com.mct.service.widgethelper.ChooserWidget.copyWidget(ChooserWidget.java:676)
    at com.mct.service.widgethelper.ChooserWidget.copyAllWidgets(ChooserWidget.java:634)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

You set ht Ids of all objects in the list:

```
abc.setId(0l);
```

And that's what causes the error. 
You cannot change an auto-generated ID by your own.

Remove this line.

Comment: but i have to clear the id because the abc has a id then no new record will be inserted into database.and the current record will be updated.

Comment: If you use the same ID, it will update the current object and wont add another one.

Answer (score 0):

In hibernate You can't set Id (Autogenrated) manulally like below.

```
abc.setId(0l);
```

Remove this above line try again.

Comment: if i remove this line then the previous record will be updated . because the abc has a id then no new record will be inserted into database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be this line:

```
abc.setId(0l);
```

You are clearing the ids of the entities you've loaded from the database.